# How to stop mouseOver text from flickering when the mouse is hovering over it

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a Javascript function to display text when you hover over the `div`.  I did this but listening to the `mouseover` event.  The text does appear when my mouse hovers over the `div`, but when the mouse hovers over the newly-appeared text within that `div` the text flickers.

How can I stop this text from flickering?  Everything else is working okay.

```
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
    var pictureContent = document.createElement("p");
    pictureContent.innerHTML = "Officially the People's<br> Republic of China, is a <br>country in East Asia and <br>the world's most <br>populous country,";
    pictureContent.style.cssText = "position:absolute"
    document.getElementById("box1").appendChild(pictureContent);
} 

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("box1").textContent = "China";
}
```

I would like the text not to flicker, even when the mouse is hovering over it.

Comment: use mouseenter/leave instead

Answer (score 0):

Include the paragraph in the HTML, and simply hide/show it by modifying its `display` attribute in CSS.

Also, as Josh Lin mentioned, use `mouseenter` & `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` & `mouseout`, so that transitions inside the `div` (from `div` to `p`) are not counted.

Working demo:

```js
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseEnter);
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeave);

function mouseEnter() {
  document.getElementById("box_para").style.display = "block";
} 

function mouseLeave() {
  document.getElementById("box_para").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#box1 {
  background:blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#box_para {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  China
  <p id="box_para">Officially the People's<br> Republic of China, is a <br>country in East Asia and <br>the world's most <br>populous country,<p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the same idea as glhr's answer, but pure css with no java script

```css
#box1 {
  background:red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  color:yellow;
  padding: 6px
}

#box_para {
  color:black;
  display: none;
}
#box1:hover > #box_para
{
  margin-left:10px;
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <h1> China </h1>
  <p id="box_para">Officially the People's<br> Republic of China, is a <br>country in East Asia and <br>the world's most <br>populous country,<p>
</div>
```